# Select2 options not aligned with bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

I'm having an issue with my select2 box. For some reason, the dropdown options appear with a left padding added, causing them to appear next to the modal.

I am using exactly the same code on other pages where it works normally. For some reason, a left padding is added and I have no idea why.

I initiate .select2 like:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#master_sku_id').select2({theme: 'bootstrap', dropdownParent: $(".modal-body")})
  return
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple modals on my page. After adding a new custom named class to my modal body it was working again. DERP!